# Ledpar prints ledmac-footnotes on new blank page if \lemma{} is used

Tags: footnotes, ledmac

As you can see from the minimal example below, ledmac-footnotes are printed on a new blank page, if the \lemma{}-command is used.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{ledmac,ledpar}  
\setcounter{firstlinenum}{1}    
\setcounter{linenumincrement}{1}
\begin{document}

\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\edtext{This is a sample text.}{\lemma{This is \ldots\ text}}
{\Bfootnote{A secondary footnote}} 
The sample text continues.

There is a new line, too.

And \edtext{at the bottom \dots}{\lemma{bottom}}
{\Afootnote{there is a critical apparatus}}
\pend

\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering

\pstart
On this page there is supposed to be the translation of the left page.
\pend

\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}

\Pages
\end{pages}

\end{document}
```

In order to get my footnotes on the page where they ought to be, I have to remove the \lemma{}-command, which in fact is quite regrettable because, for the work I'd like to do, lemmata would be very handy.
Have you any idea how this problem could be solved?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are just using `\edtext` incorrectly. It takes just two arguments. If you want to use `\lemma` you put it *in* the second argument, but you are using three "arguments". So where you have:

```
\edtext{This is a sample text.}% First argument
      {\lemma{This is \ldots\ text}}% Second argument
      {\Bfootnote{A secondary footnote}}% Third "argument", really floating group
```

You should have

```
\edtext{at the bottom \dots}% First argument
{\lemma{bottom}\Afootnote{there is a critical apparatus}}% Second argument, includes \lemma{}
```

In fact in this case you could just as well have:

```
at the \edtext{bottom}{\Afootnote{there is a critical apparatus}\ldots
```